# Proving that if $A=QR$ then $A \sim RQ$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that if: $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, $Q$ is an orthogonal $n \times n$ matrix, and $R$ is an upper triangular $n \times n$ matrix such that $A = QR$ then $A \sim RQ$

I know that $A = SQRS^{-1}$, are there some sort of properties I am missing out on that let me switch $Q$ and $R$ around in their order?

Comment: $A = QR = QR(QQ^{-1}) = Q(RQ)Q^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

From $A=QR$, we have $R=Q^TA$.  Hence  $RQ=Q^TAQ$.  But $Q$ is orthogonal, i.e. $Q^TQ=I$ or equivalently $Q^T=Q^{-1}$.  Denoting $S=Q^T$ we get $RQ=SAS^{-1}$. This last equality illustrates that $RQ$ and $A$ are similar.